# как удалить окружность в canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Столкнулся с такой проблемой . У меня есть переменная myGameArea ,содержащая объект. В нем есть метод clear ,который должен удалять отрисованные элементы в canvas.Но почему то этого не происходит.Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
let myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new Component(30, 30, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 'red')
}
let myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

//Круг
function Component(x, y, radius, startAng, endAng, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.startAng = startAng;
  this.endAng = endAng;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAng, this.endAng);
    ctx.fill();
  };

};

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.x += 1;
  myGamePiece.update()
}
startGame()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пропустили

```
ctx.beginPath()
```

От этого Вы рисовали один сложный path состоящий из окружностей из всех прошлых кадров

```js
let myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new Component(30, 30, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 'red')
}
let myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement('canvas'),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}
startGame()
//Круг
function Component(x, y, radius, startAng, endAng, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.startAng = startAng;
  this.endAng = endAng;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAng, this.endAng);
    ctx.fill();
  };

};

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.x += 1;
  myGamePiece.update()
}
```